# In the Fibonacci sequence, show that $5\mid u_m\Longleftrightarrow 5\mid m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

Knowing in the Fibonacci sequence$$u_n\mid u_m\Longleftrightarrow n\mid m$$

> Question 1: In the Fibonacci sequence, show that $$5\mid u_m\Longleftrightarrow 5\mid m$$

Proof:

> $\Longrightarrow$
>
> In the Fibonacci sequence $(1,1,2,3,5,8,...)$, $u_5=5$, therefore we have $5\mid u_m\Longrightarrow u_5\mid u_m\Longrightarrow 5\mid m\;\;\;\;\Box$
>
> $\Longleftarrow$
>
> Having that $5\mid m$ then $u_5\mid u_m\Longrightarrow5\mid u_m\;\;\;\;\Box$$$$$
> Correct?

Comment: @AhaanRungta sequence$$(1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,...)$$ soon $u_8=21$ and $7\mid 21$, if $8\mid m\Longrightarrow u_8\mid u_m\Longrightarrow 21\mid u_m$ Also do not know if I can say that $7\mid u_m$ so I need help.

Comment: Hm, I haven't solved the problem yet, but I'd try it like this. First, assume $ 6 \mid m $. Then, try to show that $ 4 \mid u_m $ using some consecutive term Euclidean Algorithm argument. Then, go for the other direction. Assume $ 4 \mid u_m $. Show that $ 6 \mid m $.

Comment: @AhaanRungta And in the case of "$\Longrightarrow$" I do not know how to do, because there is no sequence number that is 7.

Comment: Oh, hm. I was only looking at the second one: $$ 4 \mid u_m \iff 6 \mid m. $$ For the first one, if I undersatnd your exact question, $ 7 \mid 21 $, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: @AhaanRungta And in the case of 7?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "in the case of $7$?"

Comment: @AhaanRungta The 7's I think I got just use transitivity, right? Show that $21\mid u_m$ and $7\mid 21$ transitivity $7\mid u_m$

Comment: Yes, that seems about right.

Comment: @AhaanRungta I mean so ... Answer to the first part:$$$$
$\Longleftarrow$$$$$

Show: $8\mid m\Rightarrow u_8\mid u_m\Rightarrow 21\mid u_m$ as $7\mid 21$ then $7\mid u_m\;\;\;\;\Box$

Comment: @AhaanRungta And "$\Longrightarrow$", how to do?

Comment: Do you need to use the given fact? Otherwise, working modulo 7, the sequence is $(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 6, 0, 1, 1, \ldots )$. Hence $7 | u_m \Leftrightarrow 8 | m $.

Comment: @CalvinLin Sorry, did not understand the idea;

Answer (score 1):

(*partial Answer*)
**2.1**
$u_8 = 21$, so $8|m \Leftrightarrow 21|u_m \Leftrightarrow 3|u_m \wedge 7|u_m$
now if $3|u_m \Leftrightarrow 4|m$ and thus
$$8|m \Leftrightarrow 4|m \wedge 7|u_m$$
is all you can get by the requirements.

**2.2**
$$6|m \Leftrightarrow 3|m \wedge 2|m \Leftrightarrow 2|u_m \wedge 1|u_m \Leftrightarrow 2|u_m$$
Same here...

I'm open to any imprvements / suggestions

Comment: R: I tried $$7\mid u_m\Longleftrightarrow 8\mid m$$
$\Longleftarrow$$$\text{We have}\;\;8\mid m\implies u_8\mid u_m\implies 21\mid u_m\;\text{as}\;7\mid 21\Longrightarrow 7\mid u_m\;\Box$$ Propried transitivity. Only, from $7\mid u_m$ I could not solve.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior That's basically what I have written down, as $8|m \Rightarrow 4|m$

Comment: Yes, of course. But my question is, how to prove "the trip"

Comment: From $7\mid u_m$ and reach the $8\mid m$

Comment: Consider
$$F(n + 1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \left( \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} \right)^n - \left( \frac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2} \right )^n \right )$$

Comment: @AlexR Consider fixing your $\LaTeX$, please?

Comment: @AhaanRungta Sure thing, I forgot a \left (was \eft ^^)

Comment: Ah yeah, looks much better now!

Comment: @AlexR I could not understand. Sorry, do not speak English, use translator.

Comment: @AlexR I'm really sorry, but I honestly do not understand how to do it, how to solve the problem.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior No problem. $F(n+1)$ is an expanded form of $u_{n+1}$, sorry for failing to point that out.

Answer (score 1):

Mod $5$ the Fibonacci sequence is periodic of period $20$:
$$
0,1,1,2,3,0,3,3,1,4,0,4,4,3,2,0,2,2,4,1,0,1,1,2,3,0,\dots
$$
The zeros occur at $m=0,5,10,15$ and so occur exactly when $m$ is a multiple of $5$.

Actually, $u_m \equiv 2m 3^m \bmod 5$ and then the claim is clear. This is  Binet's formula mod $5$. It follows because $x^2-x-1 \equiv (x-3)^2 \bmod 5$ and so $u_m \equiv (am+b)3^m$ for some integers $a$ and $b$, which are found by considering $u_0$ and $u_1$.